# Control transmission from one instruction to next

Tags: assembly, x86-16

I am little bit confuse that after the instruction mentioned in line "line1" the control will go to GETRET and RET from there or it will skip GETRET and will move to GETPARM

```
GETONE: CALL GETPARM
OR AL, AL
JNZ GETRET
INC AL                           ;line1
GETRET: CBW
MOV CX, AX
RET
GETPARM: INC WORD PTR [PRMPNT]
RET
```

I'm confused while working on my assembly language project.

Comment: Execution always falls through to the next instruction, CBW in this case.  Once it's assemble to machine code, the CPU doesn't know about labels.  They're just zero-width targets for branches, or other references to the address of the first byte of whatever this line assembles to.

Comment: Did you add a `.` after AL, along with your `line1` comment?  Because that probably won't assemble .  Don't break the code you're commenting.

Comment: GETRET is a label or a procedure.

Comment: @vijaydidmca123 in assembly it's all labels, which _may be used_ as procedures if you `call` them. But they remain label, i.e. just placeholders for some place in memory, without any particular extra semantic.

Comment: But where will the control go when it will reach RET within GETRET (beware this time we are coming by going through "INC AL" instruction).

Comment: To the address currently on the stack, i.e. (if everything is correctly balanced) to the instruction after the last `call` that was done. From the general gist of the code, I imagine this will be the caller of GETONE.

Comment: The `jnz getret` is the other way of reaching `getret`, skipping over the `inc` instead of running it and falling through.  RET isn't "special", the CPU doesn't know about procedures.  RET is just how you write `pop ip` in x86: load a value from the stack into the program counter.  e.g. `push offset label` / `ret` is approximately the same as `jmp label` (but slower) .